# XSLT iterate array and apply generic template to sub elements(Xml to Json)

Tags: arrays, json, xml, xslt, type-conversion

I will be getting no. of xml and I have to convert them to appropriate json format using XSLT. I am able to convert everything except for array. I need to keep templates generic.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/govind-s/ccf1534b922f69d56a2ca7de606a797d) is gist **sample** example(XML, XSL and result) having scenario as - account having `m` departments having `n` employees.

XSL works fine for all scenarios including complex objects. But it doesn't apply ideal JSON formatting to an array. It appends object name as well to each individual element of the array. In actual I have very complex/nested xml, so I have to keep xslt as generic as possible.

If I add following two templates, it does not add a comma after leaf node.

```
<xsl:template match="departments">
    <xsl:text>"departments": [{</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select=".//department">
        <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
            <xsl:text>},{</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>}]</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="employees">
    <xsl:text>"employees": [{</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select=".//employee">
        <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
            <xsl:text>},{</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>}]</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

I have copied expected-result.json in gist as well. Is there any way to iterate subelement of an array and apply a template to the nested object or any other logic?

Comment: I generally use [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog) for testing quick conversion.

Comment: At the very least, you have to indicate (maybe in a variable within your XSLT) which elements need to be treated as arrays. Otherwise, there's no way your XSLT could possibly know to output a JSON array instead of an object. TBH, I don't think XSLT is a very good choice for converting XML to JSON. How do you intend to handle all of the complex escaping rules required for producing valid JSON?

Comment: @JLRishe Yes, we need to specify elements which need to be treated as array. I drafted my implementation in question. But need improvement. It's more about producing customized JSON. I just need to inform about elements which need to be treated as arrays. Everything else is handled by template which I shared.

Comment: I don't see why https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2eed618b40c6ccf2e6f836ead9ba57e7#file-result-json is JSON, isn't there a pair of curly braces around the whole content missing to make it an object?

Comment: @MartinHonnenI I have updated XSL and its result in new gist url (updated question). result.json is still not valid json, which I want to solve as a scope of this question.

Comment: If you are constrained to use XSLT 1.0, please say so. Implementing the escaping rules for JSON is not going to be easy in XSLT 1.0 (it's easy enough in 2.0 or later).

Comment: @MichaelKay Yes. we have very good functions in 2.0. But as of now, my basic challenge is to solve this question. If later versions help me to solve my question, I would like to use it.

Comment: Well, in 3.0 you could generate XDM maps and arrays rather than lexical XML, and then use the JSON output method to serialize the result; so the approach would be completely different.

Answer (score 0):

Add new template `array-obj` and call it from template where field `employees` and `departments` are matched.

```
<xsl:template name="array-obj">
    <xsl:text>{
</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
            <xsl:text>,
</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

`employees` and `departments` template needs to be modified as below. Remove curly brackets from the template.

```
<xsl:template match="employees">
    <xsl:text>"employees": [</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select=".//employee">
        <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:call-template name="array-obj"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```